# Putting single quote in the begining of column

Tags: sed, regular-expression, quoting, columns

I have a .txt file with publications for which columns are separated by a single space.
However, titles also have spaces an in order to separate the columns correctly I need to have all titles in quotes.
At the moment my data (example.txt) looks something like this:

```
1y4w 0 'my title no. 1' journal 344 471 480 2004 CODE UK 0022-2836 0070 ? 15522299 16.8768/urlspub714
1y4w 1 'my title no. 2' 3620131 
1y44 0 'my title, no. 3.' journal 433 657 661 2005 CODE UK 0028-0836 0006 ? 15654328 10.1038/papukaj03284 
2y42 1 ;my title no. 4. ' 'journal' 66 738 ? 2010 ? DK 1744-3091 ? ? 20516614 10.1107/S174430911001626X 
1y4p 0 'my title no.5. ; journal 44 6101 6121 2005 CODE US 0006-2960 0033 ? 15835899 10.1021/bi047813a 
1y4p 0 my title no.6. ; journal 44 6101 6121 2005 CODE US 0006-2960 0033 ? ? ?
```

So my idea was to:

1. put a single quote in front of the title first word and then
2. replace the semi-columns overall.

I only have problems with the first point.
Since I didn't know how to do this looking at it column-wise, I thought of the second way:
Every row (if correctly recorded) begins with 7-character string after which I want to put th quote if not already there. This string is: 4 characters (small caps or digits) then a space, then a number[0-9] and another space.

My best attempt is:

```
sed -r "s/([a-z0-9]\{4\}\s[0-9]\s)'?;?/\1'/g" example.txt >> example_corr.txt
```

That doesn't change anything, though.
Also, removing the `-r` outputs the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 51: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

I am still very new to UNIX and regular expressions, so I would appreciate any help/ explanation.

P.S. I am using Windows 10 with the built-in ssh to connect to a linux device.

**UPDATE (solved)** (not as table with columns) with this:

```
sed -E "s/([a-z0-9]{4}\s[0-9]\s)'?;?/\1'/g" example.txt >> example_corr.txt
```

So now my output is, what was desired from my first point above:

```
1y4w 0 'my title no. 1' journal 344 471 480 2004 CODE UK 0022-2836 0070 ? 15522299 16.8768/urlspub714
1y4w 1 'my title no. 2' 3620131
1y44 0 'my title, no. 3.' journal 433 657 661 2005 CODE UK 0028-0836 0006 ? 15654328 10.1038/papukaj03284
2y42 1 'my title no. 4. ' 'journal' 66 738 ? 2010 ? DK 1744-3091 ? ? 20516614 10.1107/S174430911001626X
1y4p 0 'my title no.5. ; journal 44 6101 6121 2005 CODE US 0006-2960 0033 ? 15835899 10.1021/bi047813a
1y4p 0 'my title no.6. ; journal 44 6101 6121 2005 CODE US 0006-2960 0033 ? ? ?
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Do you have multiple spaces on your lines, and if so, does it matter that they remain unchanged during the edit? Is there always a space between the single digit in the second "field" of all lines and the beginning of the title (be it the first word or the opening single quote)?

Comment: for extended regular expressions (`sed -r ...`) use `([a-z0-9]{4}` (i.e. `{...}` instead of `\{...\}`) for basic regular expressions (`sed ...` without `-r`) use `\([a-z0-9]\{4\}\s[0-9]\s\)` (i.e. `\(...\)` instead of `(...)`).

Comment: You should [edit] your question and show the expected output matching your example input.

Comment: Also, please note that `-E` is more portable than `-r` to enable regular expressions, and is the preferred option to use nowadays.

Comment: Thank you @Bodo and @AdminBee! Using -E and removing the escape from the {} worked!

Comment: `\s` is a GNU regex extension and is not portable. Suggest you use a POSIX character class such as `[:blank:]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this without the need of group capturing:

```
sed -e "s/ [ ';]*/ '/2" -e "s/ ; /' /" file
```

Output:

```
1y4w 0 'my title no. 1' journal 344 471 480 2004 CODE UK 0022-2836 0070 ? 15522299 16.8768/urlspub714
1y4w 1 'my title no. 2' 3620131 
1y44 0 'my title, no. 3.' journal 433 657 661 2005 CODE UK 0028-0836 0006 ? 15654328 10.1038/papukaj03284 
2y42 1 'my title no. 4. ' 'journal' 66 738 ? 2010 ? DK 1744-3091 ? ? 20516614 10.1107/S174430911001626X 
1y4p 0 'my title no.5.' journal 44 6101 6121 2005 CODE US 0006-2960 0033 ? 15835899 10.1021/bi047813a 
1y4p 0 'my title no.6.' journal 44 6101 6121 2005 CODE US 0006-2960 0033 ? ? ?
```